# Can there be a sentence that is true in every model of an effective theory and yet not provable in that theory?

Tags: logic, model-theory, incompleteness

Formally this is:

$\exists S [\forall \mathcal M (\mathcal (\mathcal M\models T) \to (\mathcal M \models S)) \wedge \neg (T \vdash S)]$

In English: there is a sentence in the language of an effectively generated theory $T$ that is satisfied in every model of $T$, and yet not provable in $T$.

> Can this occur in some effective logical systems other than first order logic? What are those systems?

[EDIT]In first order logic systems this cannot happen because of Godel's completeness theorem for first order logic, which implies that satisfiability corresponds to syntactical provability, so if a sentence is satisfiable in every model of a first order theory, then it must be a provable in that theory.

Comment: Looks like this can happen with second-order Peano arithmetic. See http://faculty.washington.edu/keyt/SecondOrderLogic.pdf.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I think this needs to be put as an answer, are there other kinds of logic that can also do that? like intuitionistic, others..?

Comment: You are perhaps aware, judging by your final paragraph, that this cannot happen in a finitely axiomatizable first-order theory (by Gödel's completeness theorem for the predicate calculus).  It would be better to edit that into the body of the Question.

Comment: Just take first order logic and remove all axioms and rules of inference, so nothing is provable. Then the set of logical validities will work as an example.   Or, take the first-order theory of Peano arithmetic, keep the usual inference rules, and throw out every every model except the standard one. Now Con(PA) is true in every model, but not provable. (This is very close to the situation with second-order PA.) . There are also intermediate options, for example use Heyting Arithmetic with the collection of *classical* models. Now the law of the excluded middle is valid but unprovable.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420377/henkin-vs-full-semantics-for-second-order-logic-and-multi-sorted-first-order/420441#420441

Comment: For users to write a more useful answer, it would help if you could add some additional context - what are you thinking about that led you to this question? Given the ease of generating examples, I'm afraid the XY effect (http://xyproblem.info/) may be at play here.

Comment: In second order logic, take a theory that says you're well-ordered, and that $ c_{n+1} < c_n $ for constants $ c_n $. It is contradictory, but there is no proof of $ \bot $ in it

Comment: @hardmath, Ok! I've added a not about that.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I think your examples are non effective theories. I've edited the post to address this point.

Comment: @Zuhair -   What do you mean by "effective theory"?  The empty set, Peano arithmetic, and Heyting arithmetic are all effective theories / effectively generated theories in the usual meaning of the word - they have computable axiomatizations.   The important point is that the definition of the logic itself determines both the deductive system and the collection of models - by changing either of those we can make syntactic provability differ from validity in all models.

Comment: @CarlMummert, Possibly I misunderstood you then. In the first of your examples you took out all the inference rules of logic but kept the validities. How can you stipulate the sentences for this theory in an effective manner? this is usually done recursively via inference rules starting from finitely many axioms. The other example is $PA$ restricted to the standard model, but this seem to be so strong, actually it appears to be $PA + \omega$-rule, and provability is not effective in it, and by the way it is complete. About Heyting arithmetic, I can't comment, because I know nothing of it.

Comment: In the first example, the set of sentences is the same as usual, and the collection of models is the same as usual. So the set of validities - sentences true in every model - is the same. All we have done is to eliminate all inference rules so nothing is provable. Therefore there will be many logically valid sentences, in this new logic, that are not provable.   In the second example, we do not change the axioms or inference rules at all. We just change the collection of models that we consider, making a new logic different from first order logic.  The theory is still effectively generated.

Comment: @CarlMummert, you are speaking of formal systems that has no machinery for provability, in the second there is some kind of limitation on its semantics that is not logically motivated. One can barely call such systems as "logical" systems. Anyhow. I got your point. Thanks

Comment: I would say that a classical logical system, at the level of utmost generality, includes a set of sentences, a deductive consequence relation between sets of sentences, a collection of models, and a satisfaction relation between models and sentences.  If you have a different definition of "logical system" in mind, could you clarify it in the question? Second-order logic with full semantics, in particular, is not essentially different than the second example I gave.

Comment: @CarlMummert, I think basically you've provided an answer to this question, I wasn't personally aware of those details. Thanks.